# Python and Slack API, getting channel information?

Tags: python, io, slack

I am trying to get some information from a slack feed. My plan is to use this to write messages to a device by scanning the channel for certain words.

I'm having trouble getting any information to print from my channel to see what kind of information I have or how to use any of it at all.

I've tried reading the documentation and examples and can't seem to find any answers as to why this very simple code seems to keep failing for me with a key error.

Anyway, heres the code. Maybe you can help. Thanks.

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os

slack_token = "xoxp-173120660817xxxxxxxxxxf"
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)
fishtankchannel = "#fishtank"
sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=fishtankchannel, text="worked")
testinfo = sc.api_call("channels.info", channel=fishtankchannel)
print testinfo["channel"]["name"]
```

Fails at line 9 for a keyerror. the post message command works, my slack key is valid.

Comment: `print(testinfo)` to see what it contains? KeyErrors are thrown when a dict key doesnt exist but is requested.

Comment: if I change the print to 
    print(testinfo) 
It prints, but says that it has no information. I'm not sure how it could fail to gather information from a channel it JUST sent a message into.

Comment: Figured it out. 

Though my postmessage worked with the channel being the displayed name in slack, to ask it for information (channels.info) I needed to get the encoded name for the channel.

I imagine theres a better way to do this, but what I did was change and print the command channels.list then find the channel ID I was looking for, and put that in place of my channel name on the channels.info call.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Though my postmessage worked with the channel being the displayed name in slack, to ask it for information (channels.info) I needed to get the encoded name for the channel. I imagine theres a better way to do this, but what I did was change and print the command channels.list then find the channel ID I was looking for, and put that in place of my channel name on the channels.info call.

Comment: You may want to include the _working_ code. See [answer].